# Why does this XSD-validation lead to an error

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd

I've got an XSD to validate a XML-file before importing it into an other program. It worked already for 1 week. But yesterday the validation failed an I don't know why.

The error occurs at the validation of the email-adress. This is the validation of the email-adress in the XSD-file:

```
<simpleType name="EMailAdressType">
    <annotation>
        <documentation></documentation>
    </annotation>
    <restriction base="string">
        <pattern value="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">
        </pattern>
        <minLength value="0"></minLength>
        <maxLength value="64"></maxLength>
        <pattern value="\s*"></pattern>
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

And this is my C#-methode to validate a XML-file against a XSD-file:

```
public static List<string> ValidateXMLAgainstXSD(string xmlPath, string xsdPath, string targetNamespace)
{
    /// Rückgabeliste für die Validierungsfehler
    List<string> validationErrors = new List<string>();

    /// Klasse für die XML-Schemas (XSD-Dateien)
    XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
    /// Neues XML-Schema hinzufügen
    schemas.Add(targetNamespace, xsdPath);

    /// Das XML-Dokument, das validiert werden soll
    XDocument custOrdDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);

    /// Validierungs-Vorgang
    custOrdDoc.Validate(schemas, (o, e) =>
    {
        validationErrors.Add(e.Message);
    });

    /// Validierungsfehlerliste zurück geben
    return validationErrors;
}
```

The error-message is (translated by myself from german to english):

> This element 'EMailAdress' is not valid - The value
>   'mayer_johann75@web.de' is because of his datatype
>   'http://www.abcde.de/mhr/applicants/:EMailAdressType' not valid --
>   Pattern-restriction failed..

When I take the Pattern from the XSD-file and try the validation from the email-adress-string directly with the Regex-Class then it is valid...

What is wrong?

Comment: I think the under-score ('_') is causing an issue.  It is not a \w (word character).  I think using [-+_.'] (adding the underscore) will solve issue.   Note the underscore is getting removed

Comment: Agreed, underscore is not a word character. But note, you need to be aware that the Microsoft .NET XSD processor does not implement regular expressions as defined in the W3C spec, it has its own interpretation. I don't know precisely what its rules are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by the earlier comments, .Net interprets \w differently to w3c. For .Net its equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_] whereas for XSD schemas, the \w option doesn't include the underscore. Just replace all those \w with [A-Za-z0-9_] and everything should be fine.